# Not all assets in private folder of Meteor project are auto-deployed to ".meteor\local\build\programs\server\assets\app"

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, assets, private

I am using a private folder in my Meteor project to store/use static (private) assets (e.g., .json and .js files) which can be loaded using Assets.getText(assetFileName). These are normally deployed on meteor startup from "projectdir\private" to "projectdir.meteor\local\build\programs\server\assets\app".

However, of the three .js files that I have in my private directory, only two are deployed; one of them remains absent. I am trying to use that file in the exact same way (part of a loop that finds and processes all files in a directory), but Meteor simply doesn't deploy the file to the aforementioned directory, as a result of which I am met with a file-does-not-exist error for "platform_b.js".

"platform_a.js" and "platform_c.js" *can* be found (i.e., are deployed) and all three of them are present in the private folder, but (auto-)deployment fails for "platform_b.js". Deleting the deployment directory and/or rerunning does not seem to solve the issue. Any thoughts? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can this possibly be a wrong syntax that doesn't trigger an error? Other than that if you create a package you might have more control and know if something is included or not.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I don't think that's the case, since everything is done in a loop that handles each case similarly. However, I wrote a routine that manually checks for the deployed file; I could just as well check for the presence of the non-deployed file (is sufficient). I might be checking for the presence of deployed files early on before deployment is complete. That's currently the only thing that I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. You can load the private file in your code like this to force loading the assets.

```
Assets.getBinary('path/to/file')
```